# How can I troubleshoot an "hello world" program in Qt Designer?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I tried to follow just the first part of this guide:
http://talk.maemo.org/archive/index.php/t-39879.html
to make only the hello world part work. It doesn't

here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helloworld2.py", line 69, in <module>
    mainWindow = MainWin(None, "main window")
  File "helloworld2.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.setupUi(rootWidget)
  File "helloworld2.py", line 25, in setupUi
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
AttributeError: 'QWidget' object has no attribute 'setCentralWidget'
```

Should this be working(after tweaking), or should I go a whole different route? 
If it should be working, what are the things to do to troubleshoot?

Here are the ingredients of the .py file. I'm not sure I have it entered into here correctly, I'm not sure I understand the correct way to enter it, so it will appear the same as in the file. If this doesn't look right I'll try again.

```
from PyKDE4 import kdecore
from PyKDE4 import kdeui
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(800, 400)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 110, 271, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(24)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(kdecore.i18n(_fromUtf8("MainWindow")))
    self.label.setText(kdecore.i18n(_fromUtf8("Hello World!")))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    global app
class MainWin(kdeui.KMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__ (self, *args):
        kdeui.KMainWindow.__init__ (self)
        rootWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setupUi(rootWidget)
        self.resize(640, 480)
        self.setCentralWidget(rootWidget)

appName     = "default"
catalog     = ""
programName = kdecore.ki18n("default")
version     = "1.0"
description = kdecore.ki18n("Default Example")
license     = kdecore.KAboutData.License_GPL
copyright   = kdecore.ki18n("unknown")
text        = kdecore.ki18n("none")
homePage    = ""
bugEmail    = "email"

aboutData   = kdecore.KAboutData(appName, catalog, programName, version, description,
                          license, copyright, text, homePage, bugEmail)
kdecore.KCmdLineArgs.init(sys.argv, aboutData)

app = kdeui.KApplication()
mainWindow = MainWin(None, "main window")
mainWindow.show()
app.lastWindowClosed.connect(app.quit)
app.exec_ ()
```

Comment: It would be help full if you could try and separate the narrative part of the question from the actual question. Good that you took the step to join us though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your code is a little messed up, see if this is working for you and take it on from there:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyKDE4 import kdecore, kdeui
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

appName     = "default"
catalog     = ""
programName = kdecore.ki18n("default")
version     = "1.0"
description = kdecore.ki18n("Default Example")
license     = kdecore.KAboutData.License_GPL
copyright   = kdecore.ki18n("unknown")
text        = kdecore.ki18n("none")
homePage    = ""
bugEmail    = "email"
aboutData   = kdecore.KAboutData(appName, catalog, programName, version, description,
                          license, copyright, text, homePage, bugEmail)

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(800, 400)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 110, 271, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(24)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(kdecore.i18n(_fromUtf8("MainWindow")))
        self.label.setText(kdecore.i18n(_fromUtf8("Hello World!")))

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import  sys

    kdecore.KCmdLineArgs.init(sys.argv, aboutData)
    app = kdeui.KApplication()
    main = MainWindow()
    main.resize(640, 480)
    main.show()
    app.lastWindowClosed.connect(app.quit)
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Changing QWidget to QMainWindow allowed it to run. The hello world lable does not show up, that doesn't matter for my purposes, however if it would be best for the forum to try to fix that part I am more than willing to continue.

Comment: @TimBerry Checkout [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14076463/1006989), I edited the code you posted to allow your app to run

Comment: Yes, the code you posted ran for me, complete with the "hello world" on the window.